# I'm getting Trapfinding from Rogue and Scout, what can I trade one of them for?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, rogue

As title says: Since I'm multiclassing into both Rogue and Scout, I have the Trapfinding ability granted to me from two different classes, and as far as I know they don't stack or improve upon each other at all.

Currently what I know of are three ACF's for the Rogue that would work.

- Antiquarian (CC, p 51): lose trapfinding, gain wisdom bonus on appraise checks with divine items. Can attempt to identify divine items, as per the spell.
- Drow Rogue (DU, p 58): lose trapfinding, gain poison use.
- Mimic (EoE, p 21): lose trapfinding, gain disguise self.

Is there anything else out there that I can work with?  With the build I'm going for the Drow Rogue looks the most viable but really poison use appears to be more trouble than it's worth (especially with the cost of decent poisons...)

Basic level progression is Rogue1/Scout3/Ranger1/Scout1/RogueX, I'm starting the campaign at lv6.  (Would be lv7 but I'm using a Dark (LA+1) Lesser Tiefling, and LA buyoff is allowed).  Feats by lv6 are: True Believer (1); Point-Blank Shot (1); Darkstalker (1); Deadly Aim (3); Swift Hunter (6); Swift Ambusher (6).  This is to get me able to get both Swift Hunter and Swift Ambusher by level 6, and progress in Rogue after. So, I get Favored Enemy: Undead, Skirmish, and Sneak Attack. (all levels stack for Skirmish, and I can Skirmish undead)

Among my gear are various means to stay out of direct light as much as possible to use HiPS from the Dark template, as well as a Raptor arrow and a bow enchanted with an infinite On Use Sniper's Shot spell effect.  Feats on my list to get ASAP are Vital Strike and Improved Skirmish, and gear to get later include Gloves of Agile Striking (improved), Skirmisher's Boots (improved), and Rogue's Vest.

This build is aimed at shooting one arrow per round, and having that arrow bring as much pain as I can stack onto it.

We do not play a high optimization game in our group, so I'm happy with this build in general even though it is not optimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [alternative class features thread](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=7908), here are your options:

**Rogue**

- Antiquarian – +Wis to Appraise for divine items, can attempt to *identify* divine items
- Changeling Rogue – 10+Int skills/level, one Knowledge skill of choice as class skill, gain Social Intuition (several special features with social skills)
- Drow Rogue – Poison Use
- Mimic – *Disguise self*

**Scout**
(none)

So only one that you missed, but it’s a **really** good one. Anyway, rogue/scout seems like a kind of poor multiclass to me; they overlap on a lot of things and their primary differences don’t synergize very well (rogue wants to flank, scout wants to move).

> With the build I'm going for the Drow Rogue looks the most viable but really poison use appears to be more trouble than it's worth (especially with the cost of decent poisons...)

Poison Use is *almost* useless; if you want to specialize in poison, you *really* want the Master of Poisons feat from *Drow of the Underdark*, which gives you Poison Use **and** the ability to poison a weapon as a Swift action.

That said, poisons can be worthwhile, and better you *can* make decent use of poisons without investing heavily in them. Having Poison Use rather than Master of Poisons is mediocre, but Craft (poisonmaking) can generate substantial savings on poisons (prices as low as ⅙ the base cost). Tossing a few points in Craft (poisonmaking), carefully selecting cost-effective poisons, and having Poison Use can give you a fairly potent low-level option.

For more about making the most of poison, check out [Arsenic and Old Lace](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=2714.0).

Comment: Details from comments have been folded in to the question and comments cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

See if your DM would allow you a bonus feat as an alternative.  He or she could approve it as fair, since imho feats vary wildly in power level. There are many that could give a significant boost to your archer.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Dungeonscape Pg 12/13, a Ranger can lose Track and gain Trapfinding as an Alternate class feature. I have had several DMs allow me to do the reverse.